# Setup cocos2d-release-3.0-rc1 project for win32

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Hey guys i wanna setup cocos2d version 3.0 for windows. Currently I am using visual studio 2010 and cocos2d 2.2.2 for building apps. As cocos2d version 3.0 released so i want to upgrade cocos2d 2.2.2 to cocos2d 3.0. Is cocos2d 3.0 stable version released? and how can i integrate it with visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cocos2d-x v3 is officially released: http://cocos2d-x.org/news/216

Here are Windows instructions: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Windows